# flask jwt extended how to pass audience

Tags: python, jwt, flask-jwt-extended

I am trying to pass audience as a parameter in flask jwt extended for decoding jwt token, My code is like this,

```
@app.route('/api')
@jwt_required
def my_api():
    return json.dumps('Welcome ')
```

when i call my api i am getting

```
{
    "msg": "Invalid audience"
}
```

I know, we have to provide audience value. However i am not sure how to pass audience in `jwt_required` in `flask_jwt_extended`. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Flask-JWT-Extended is very opinionated about that claims need to be in a token for all of the extra features to work. If you are getting your JWTs from a different provider, chances are very high that you should be using Flask-JWT-Simple instead. You can view some discussions about it here: https://github.com/vimalloc/flask-jwt-extended/issues/85